# opencv cvCaptureFromFile("url") equivalent for java?

Tags: java, image-processing, opencv

i'm trying to connect to ip camera from java using openCV.
I see examples of C code where people were using cvCaptureFromFile("url") method, providing proper url and connecting to camera, but the thing is that THERE IS NO SUCH METHOD IN JAVA!!!

Please help if you have any suggestions.

Your help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you use the [Java Native Interface](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jni.html) to interface to the C++ or C API version of OpenCV.

In any case, I'd recommend using C++ for general OpenCV/image processing. Boost will satisfy your needs in terms of library support, etc.

Comment: Sorry i'm not sure i understand your solution, JNI allows to add C library but, i also need corresponding Java interface i will work with, am i right?
You are suggesting to add missing method manually?

Comment: You write the Java function prototypes which wrap the C/C++ libraries. Just try an example and it will become clear. This is the approach I took to get OpenCV's face detection working on Android.